# Is there a way to change the __add__ method in python to be able to add a string and an int using only the + operator?

Tags: python, addition

Is there a way to rewrite the `__add__` method in the `str` class so that this operation is possible without an exception occurring:

```
"apple" + 123
```

This error keeps popping up:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code?

Comment: I suppose you could patch the built-in class using e.g. https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit, but why don't you use `'apple{}'.format(123)` or one of the other string formatting methods? Python is **strongly typed**, it's weird to patch things to undo that.

Comment: The '_ _add__' method would only allow modification for derived classes, not for the built-in standard types.

Comment: @renee> btw, this error is not a problem, it is intentionally here to tell you you are adding mismatched things, which is ambiguous ("2"+2 should be "22" or 4?). To prevent you from writing erroneous code, the interpreter makes you write your actual intention explicitly: either `int("2")+2` or `"2"+str(2)`. We say the language is strongly typed.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the most pythonic solution would be co convert `123` to `str`. All you need to do to get "apple123" is `"apple" + "123"` or `"apple" + str(123)`.

Comment: Even more pythonic would be to use `join`, but actually I find `+` more readable :)

Comment: For just 2 strings join should provide no benefit, so + is okay.

Comment: @kazemakase Can you elaborate a bit more why `join` is more pythonic? PEP8 only says it could be faster (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - No. You can not "override" the basic classes, but you can however provide a new subclass, but you will need to do it for both the strings and the integers, and then declare each item as an instance of your new class, which is pointless because the alternative is to simply do this:

```
myvar = 'apple' + str(123)
```

You could however write a helper function to take care of that for you, if you're extremely lazy :) something like this:

```
def stradd(a,b):
    return str(a)+str(b)
```

And from then on just use `stradd('apple',123)` to add things together

Answer (score -2):

You can use a function in your program to check before adding.
For example:
    `def check(object1):
         if type(object1)==int:
             return str(object1)
         else:
             return object1
print 'string'+check(123)`

gives output:`>>> string123>>>`
You cannot overide the **add**() method but you can use your own user defined class to change the way **add**() works in your defined class's objects. If you need the code ask me. 
**EDIT**

```
def check(object1):
     if type(object1)==int:
         return str(object1)
     else:
         return object1
print 'string'+check(123)
```

Comment: Please perform your typechecks using `isinstance(var, cls)`.